# iText - Error in Acrobat Reader when creating too many cells containing a TextField and using a PageEvent

Tags: java, itext, acrobat

I have a question regarding iText (2.1.7).
I create a table which has TextFields in every cell at the moment. The TextFields are added with a PdfPCellEvent. I found this example on the iText Website and tried it out. It all works fine - until my table reaches a specific length. Then Acrobat Reader tells me, that there is an error on the page and that it might be displayed wrong. Nevertheless the table and the fields work, they are just slow (when changing fields, etc). When I open the PDF in Foxit Reader there is no error so I assume that there is a performance issue and Acrobat Reader cannot handle it. 
I tried to split my table into smaller tables then and did 5 tables with 10 rows instead of one table with 50 rows - but the same problem occurs.

I now search for a way to increase the performance of my code, so that I can add a lot of rows without having this error message in Acrobat Reader.

This is my code:
First the PdfPCellEvent:

```
    class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected String fieldname;
    protected String content;

    public MyCellField(String fieldname, String content) {
        this.fieldname = fieldname;
        this.content = content;
    }


    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {

        PdfWriter writer = canvases[PdfPTable.BASECANVAS].getPdfWriter();
        TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
        textField.setRotation(90);
        textField.setFont(inside_textbox.getBaseFont());
        textField.setFontSize(inside_textbox.getSize());
        textField.setText(content);

        PdfFormField field;
        try {
            field = textField.getTextField();
            writer.addAnnotation(field);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

(I rotate the Textfield because the document is landscape)
And this is the place where i use it:

```
    PageNumeration event = new PageNumeration();
    writer.setPageEvent(event);

    document.open();

    PdfPTable table= new PdfPTable(8); 
    table.setWidths(new float[] {30,160,320,170,65,85,85,85}); 
    table.setWidthPercentage(80);
    table.setKeepTogether(false);

    table= createTableHeads(document, table);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    PdfPCell cell;

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {   

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("a"+i, "a"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("b"+i, "b"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("c"+i, "c"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("d"+i, "d"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("e"+i, "e"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("f"+i, "f"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("g"+i, "g"));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setMinimumHeight(mtp(4));
        cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("h"+i, "h"));
        table.addCell(cell);

    }

    document.add(table);

    document.close();
```

mtp() is just a shorter writing for Utilities.millimetersToPoints. And createTableHeads adds 8 cells with plain text in it to the table before adding all the Textfield-Cells.

Are there any ideas on how to avoid the error message I get?

**EDIT**
I just noticed that actually my PageNumeration Event causes trouble if the table gets too long. But still its not obvious for my why it does so.  This is the PageNumerationEvent:

```
 private class PageNumeration extends PdfPageEventHelper{

    PdfTemplate allPages;

    @Override
    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

        allPages = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(50, 50);
        allPages.setFontAndSize(standard_text.getBaseFont(), standard_text.getSize());
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.beginText();
        try {
            Rectangle pageSize = document.getPageSize();
            cb.setFontAndSize(standard_text.getBaseFont(), standard_text.getSize());
            String s = "( " + writer.getPageNumber() + " / ";
            cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, s, pageSize.getWidth() /2, document.bottomMargin(), 0);
            cb.addTemplate(allPages, pageSize.getWidth() /2 + standard_text.getBaseFont().getWidthPoint(s, 4), document.bottomMargin());
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        cb.endText();

    }


    @Override
    public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

        allPages.beginText();
        try {
            allPages.setFontAndSize(standard_text.getBaseFont(), standard_text.getSize());
            allPages.setTextMatrix(0f, 0f);
            allPages.showText("" + (writer.getPageNumber() -1) + " )");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        allPages.endText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error message when you use iText 5.5.10?

Comment: No, i cannot reproduce it when i try it with iText 5. Seems like this fixes it. So there is no possible way to get around this in iText 2.1.7? Sadly its not my decision which iText version I can use... :(

Comment: It seems that the problem is fixed, now all you have to do, is to [convince your boss](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/ConvinceLetter.pdf). Have confidence in yourself; we know you can do it!

Comment: Ah, while I was trying to convert the whole class to iText5 and trying only pieces of the code in iText 2 i noticed that actually my PageNumeration Event causes this problem IF there are too many rows... With just a few rows its fine. I will edit the question...

Comment: Adding a template inside a text block is not valid according to the pdf specification.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! :)